# Remove double tag from string

Tags: java, regex

I have a String look like this :

```
<start> <start> some sentence <stop> is a sentence <stop>
```

How I can make those String something like this :

```
<start> some sentence is a sentence <stop>
```

So far I'm using regex to remove the double start first

```
string.replace("<start> <start>","<start>");
```

but I'm still stuck at removing the middle stop tag.

Comment: other way can be looking for last index of substring `<start>` and removing it completely, but it can be messy

Comment: or you can count for occurrences if there are many `<start>` and start removing one by one except first occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do like below `replaceFirst` is `String` class method which replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

```
String finalResult=string.replaceFirst("<start>", "" ).replaceFirst("<stop>", "" )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about Start and Stop Tags in Starting & Ending. You can also hardcode them manually and remove all the tags in-between.

```
public class myclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "<start> <start> some sentence <stop> is a sentence <stop>";
        String finalResult="<start>"+x.replaceAll("<[^>]+>", "")+"<stop>";
        System.out.println(finalResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, you can just remove all of the instances and then fix the String how you want it:

```
private static final String START = "<start>";
private static final String STOP = "<stop>";

private boolean containsKeywords(final String string) {
    return string.contains(START) ||
        string.contains(STOP);
}

private String stripAllStartStop(final String string) {
    string.replaceAll(START, "");
    string.replaceAll(STOP, "");
}

private addStartStop(final String string) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.add(START);
    sb.add(string);
    sb.add(STOP);
    return sb.build();
}  

/**
 * Cleanup the sequence of START and STOP tokens in a String.
 */
public String sanitizeString(final String string) {
    if (containsKeywords(string)) {
        return addStartStop(stripAllStartStop(string));
    }
}
```

The better, cleaner, and more extensible way is similar, but using [`StrSubstitutor`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html) using a lookup `Map` for the replacements.

Answer (score 0):

The stop you want to remove is wrapped by empty spaces to the right AND left use that as criteria to remove the one you need..

```
string.replace(" <stop> ","");
```